# How to make featured area?

Tags: widgets, dropdown

I'm trying to make custom wp theme, but i have one thing that i don't know how to make.
I would like to make featured area on my page like this for example:
http://prntscr.com/7gespg
I made widget that select pages from dropdown but i don't know how to display them on my page. This is the code:

```
class featured_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct(){

        $params = array(
            'description' => 'Display messages to readers',
            'name'        => 'Fetured Widget '
            );

        parent::__construct('featuredwidget','',$params);
    }

    function form($instance){

        for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 

            wp_dropdown_pages(array(
               'selected'              => $instance['link_target_'.$i],
               'name'                  => $this->get_field_name('link_target_'.$i),
               'id'                    => $this->get_field_id('link_target_'.$i),
               'echo'                  => 1,
               ));
        }
    }

    function widget($args, $instance){

        print_r($instance);
        print_r($args);

    }
}
add_action('widgets_init','ak_featured_widget');
 function ak_featured_widget(){
   register_widget('featured_widget');
 }
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `update` method which saves your widget settings:

```
function update( $new_instance, $instance ) {
    for ( $i=0; $i < 3; $i++ )
        $instance[ "link_target_$i" ] = $new_instance[ "link_target_$i" ];

    return $instance;
}
```

Comment: ty for response.
But problem is that i don't get anything in $args or $instance when i print_r them in widget().
Any idea?